# Cannot bind source type to model type USNStarterKit.USNModels.USNBaseViewModel

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to a add a new Search feature in my website. This search feature searches from another database. 
This is my Model :
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r16rG.jpg)

This is my Controller :
[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhQus.jpg)

This is my View :
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB9UM.jpg)

This is my Solution Explorer :
[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY4wz.jpg)

Can someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong and I keep on getting this error :
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvH0Y.jpg)

Also my Document Type name is the same as the name of my Controller and my Template name is same as the Action name I am using in my Controller. 
What am I doing wrong here ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your code - from the parts you show, looks ok.

There are 2 possibilities:

1. you are overlooking something e.g. looking at the wrong page, not compiling your C#, configuring the wrong template, ...
2. there is a default controller messing around.  But I would ask the *unskinned* support as you bought a theme from them.